# VueJS/Typescript - Cannot find module './components/Navigation' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

When I create a script as typescript (lang="ts") I get an error stating

> "Cannot find module './components/Navigation' or its corresponding type declarations (Vetur 2307).".

I realized that this only happens when I set the lang as ts, which is what I need to build my Vue application.

app.vue

```
<template>
  <Navigation />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Navigation from './components/Navigation'; // This is where I get the error message

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Navigation,
  }
}
</script>
```

Navigation.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="nav">
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> 
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link> 
    <router-link to="/categories">Categories</router-link> 
    <router-link to="/random">Random</router-link>
  </div>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  name: 'Navigation',
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In the `src` folder add the file `shims-vue.d.ts` with the following content :

Vue 2 :

```
declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  export default Vue
}
```

Vue 3:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}
```

and import the component with its extension `.vue` :

```
 import Navigation from './components/Navigation.vue';
```

instead of :

```
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';
```

Comment: As per [this github comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5549#issuecomment-638850440):  

_"It is expected behavior... In the next major version, we'll stop supporting extension-less import of single file components at all (currently there's only the type checking error)."_

Comment: Thanks, I just had the same error and was able to fix it with the shim file. I wish the official Vue 3 Typescript documentation and guide would tell you that you need this. *sighs*

Comment: I was importing my component using `.vue`, however was still receiving the module import error as noted in this thread. I was able to create the `shims-vue.d.ts` file, along with updating my `tsconfig.json` in the root Vue app directory. Here's the [thread on vue/vetur github](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/2875) that helped me. It seemed like I had to implement both fixes to resolve a whole slough of errors (that never prevented compile). I wish this was setup better out of the box as is a time sink just to get going. 