# Vue 3 default project vetur cannot find module

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vetur

When I install a Vue 3 Typescript project with vue `create hello-world` I get the following error in the Home.vue

```
Cannot find module '@/components/HelloWorld.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.Vetur(2307)
```

on line

```
import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.vue"; // @ is an alias to /src
```

Edit: I noticed that it is happening because I am working in a workspace with 3 other folders. If I open the folder seperately I get no error.

Comment: Try calling it as a relative path, something like '../components/HelloWorld.vue'

Comment: Also, did you just installed Vetur on VS Code? Try restarting the VS Code.

Comment: I can run the application it just shows the error in vscode. I did restart VS Code and it did not go away

Comment: please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64213710/8172857)

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix it

Comment: I'm getting this same error. Vetur doesn't seem to work currently with monorepos / tsconfig.json files.