# Splitting component's files (with typescript)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Our team is starting a new project based on Vue 3 for front end part.

We decided to use TypeScript and would like to use the separation of file approach.
We found [this article](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#What-About-Separation-of-Concerns) in the doc showing an example to achieve this. Unfortunately, this example doesn't show how to achieve this with TypeScript.

We tried this way

```
/components
┗ /SideBarBtn
  ┣ sidebar-btn.scss
  ┣ sidebar-btn.ts
  ┗ sidebar-btn.vue
```

**sidebar-btn.vue**

```html
<template>
    <h1 class="test">This is a test</h1>
</template>
<script lang="ts" src="./sidebar-btn.ts"></script>
<style lang="scss" src="./sidebar-btn.scss"></style>
```

**sidebar-btn.scss**

```css
.test {
    color: blue;
}
```

**sidebar-btn.ts**

```js
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "SideBarBtn",
});
```

**Home.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png" />
    <SideBarBtn />
  </div>
</template>
```

The command `npm run serve` does execute correctly and page loads. But the component isn't visible and warning is printed in console `Component is missing template or render function.`

How can we fix this?

Comment: Use import statement to import the ts files in the component instead of using script tag in the sidebar-btn.vue file inside the script tag
`import {file} from path`

Comment: `<script lang="ts">import SideBarBtn from './sidebar-btn'</script>` in `sidebar-btn.vue` doesn't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the `<script>` tag of the `Home.vue`. The SideBarBtn was imported using the aliases method @/... and doesn't work atm.

**Home.vue**

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import SideBarBtn from "../components/SideBarBtn/sidebar-btn.vue"; // The name of the vue file has to be complete, with .vue extension

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    SideBarBtn
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: please check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64213710/8172857

Comment: `shims-vue.d.ts` is already created like you are suggesting it when you use Vue CLI with TypeScript option. The only thing I had to change is to import the fully file name, including extension. 

It is working fine now!