# webpack failed to import App.vue or other component vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

i am currently create a webpack based and add in the vue3 with typescript.
But right now i am facing the problem which is
 `TS2307: Cannot find module './App.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.`
[image]

The shsims-vue.d.ts is currently set under src folder, and it is generated by the default.

```
/* eslint-disable */
import VueRouter, { Route } from 'vue-router'

declare module '*.vue' {
    import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
    const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
    export default component

}
```

This is my tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "esnext",
      "module": "esnext",
      "strict": true,
      "jsx": "preserve",
      "importHelpers": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "types": [
        "webpack-env"
      ],
      "paths": {
        "@/*": [
          "src/*"
        ]
      },
      "lib": [
        "esnext",
        "dom",
        "dom.iterable",
        "scripthost"
      ]
    },
    "include": [
      "src/**/*.ts",
      "src/**/*.tsx",
      "src/**/*.vue",
      "tests/**/*.ts",
      "tests/**/*.tsx"
, "src/shims-vue.d.ts"    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
```

Here are my webpack configuration file

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const utils = require('./utils')
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/main.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'main.[hash].bundle.js'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
        alias: {
            'vue': '@vue/runtime-dom'
        }
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        port: 9000,
        hot: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: {
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.png/,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "vue-loader",
                }
            },
        ]
    },
    // to see the source code in browser 
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './public/index.html'
        }),
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'main.[hash].css'
        })
    ]
}
```

In other component also facing this error, kind of no clue how this happen and how to resolve. Please give some light for this. Thanks.

Comment: it should work as I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64213710/8172857) just  restart the npm run serve and the vscode editor

Comment: Ya, i search for some result are like that, but after few times retry still the same. The error still there. @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: Try out to replace the first rule by this one `{ test : /\.ts$/, use: [ 'babel-loader', { loader: 'ts-loader', options: { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/], }, }, ], },`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim i tried add the rules that you commented, but still the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VueJS/Typescript - Cannot find module './components/Navigation' or its corresponding type declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64213461/vuejs-typescript-cannot-find-module-components-navigation-or-its-correspon)