# TypeScript error "Cannot find module" (Vetur 2307) that I cannot resolve

Tags: typescript, vue.js

In one of my TypeScript files I am importing a Vue component using this line:

`import KTUserMenu from "@/layout/header/partials/UserMenu.vue";`

But it is giving me this TypeScript error:

`Cannot find module '@/layout/header/partials/UserMenu.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.`

These are my `tsconfig.json` options:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

As [per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64213461/vuejs-typescript-cannot-find-module-components-navigation-or-its-correspon), I also have a `shims-vue.d.ts` file in the `src` folder with the following content, but it does not solve the problem:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}
```