# NuxtJS : problem import ing Component in mixin

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-property-decorator

my stacks are **Nuxtjs** and **Nuxt-property-decorator**

I've made a mixin to avoid repeating a method

that method need a component ( Alert component )

so , I imported that component in mixin

**But** i have error for importing component

Note : i am sure import address is true

**mixin/logOut.ts**
import Vue from 'vue'

```
import { Component } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
import AppAlert from '~/components/Common/AppAlert'
@Component
export class LogOut extends Vue {
  async LogOut() {
    const confirm = await this.$dialog.show({
      component: AppAlert,
      props: {
        title: { text: 'Exit ?', icon: 'exclamation-thick' },
        body: 'Exit Connector ?',
        btn: { text: 'Confirm', icon: 'power', color: 'error' }
      }
    })
    
    if (confirm) {
      this.$auth.logout()
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

error text is :

```
Cannot find module '~/components/Common/AppAlert' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

Comment: What happens if you write `AppAlert.ts` here? Because I'm supposing that it defaults to `.js` if you don't write the extension.

Comment: AppAlert is a component and its extenion is .vue ,
i added .vue and it didn't fix

Comment: Maybe try to check [this one](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5298) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64213461/vuejs-typescript-cannot-find-module-components-navigation-or-its-correspon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer from [this link](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5298).

I added

`vue-shims.d.ts`

```
declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  export default Vue
}
```